# handing string to MATLAB function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

In my Simulink Model I have a MATLAB function, `this_function`, which uses as one parameter the name of the Simulink Model, `modelname`. The name is defined in an extra parameter file with all other parameters needed. Loading the parameter file loads `modelname` into the workspace. The problem is now, that `this_function` can't access `modelname` in the workspace and therefore the model doesn't run.

I tried to use `modelname` as a constant input source for `this_function`, which I used as a work-around previously, but Simulink doesn't accept chars/strings as signals. Furthermore does setting `modelname` to global not work as well.

Is there a way to keep `modelname` in the parameter file instead of writing it directly into `this_function`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulink does not support strings. Like, anywhere. It really sucks and I don't know why this limitation exists - it seems like a pretty horrible design choice to me.

I've found the following workarounds for this limitation:

### Dirty Casting

Let

```
function yourFun(num_param1, num_param2, ..., str_param);
```

be your MATLAB function inside the Simulink block, with `str_param` the parameter you want to be a string, and `num_param[X]` any other parameters. Then pass the string signal to the function like so:

```
yourFun(3, [4 5], ..., 'the_string'+0);
```

Note that '`+0`' at the end; that is shorthand for casting a string to an array of integers, corresponding to the ASCII codes of each character in the string. Then, inside the function, you *could* get the string back by doing the inverse:

```
model = char(str_param);
```

but usually that results in problems later on (`strcmp` not supported, `upper/lower` not supported, etc.). So, you could do string comparisons (and similar operations) in a similar fashion:

```
isequal(str_param, 'comparison'+0);
```

This has all the benefits of strings, without actually using strings.

Of course, the '`+0`' trick can be used inside constant blocks as well, model callbacks to convert workspace variables on `preLoad`, etc.

Note that support for variable size arrays must be enabled in the MATLAB function.

### Fixed Option Set

Instead of passing in a string, you can pass a numeric scalar, which corresponds to a selection in a list of fixed, hardcoded options:

```
function yourFun(..., option)

    ...

    switch (option)
        case 1 
            model = 'model_idealised';
        case 2
            model = 'model_with_drag';
        case 3
            model = 'model_fullscale';
        otherwise
            error('Invalid option.');
    end

    ...

end
```

Both alternatives are not ideal, both are contrived, and both are prone to error and/or have reusability and scalability problems. It's pretty hopeless.

Simulink should start supporting strings natively, I mean, *come on*.

Comment: So I used the dirty casting option. That worked, I could extract the string out of the array with `char()`. It's not beautiful, but serves the purpose.